# Python Pandas: Filling data frame with pd.Series in each element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The library sktime requires a very "particular" [data format](https://alan-turing-institute.github.io/sktime/examples/loading_data.html). For n time series the T values of each series need to be stored in a pandas Dataframe of pandas Series of length T like this:

DataFrame:

```
index |   Data  
   0  | pd.Series
   1  | pd.Series 
  ... |    ...   
 n-1  | pd.Series
```

My attempt to fill an empty data frame with n = 2 and T = 3 in a loop by reading from another data frame did not work. Here is my reduced version that uses a constant pd.Series in each row:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Data"])
for i in range(2):
    df.loc[i] = pd.Series([2, 4, 5])
```

Note that from many examples on the site, I know (1) how to fill a normal data frame in a for loop and (2) my attempt is not efficient even if it was working.

Comment: Can we see what your input data looks like? Maybe a toy example that we can try. Thanks.

Comment: Such an interesting design choice. it's purposely very difficult to create a DataFrame with Series in a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas doesn't want you to store complex objects in a cell, so if you try to create a DataFrame from Series, pandas will flatten it to a 2-d structure. To avoid that we need to work with a `Series`; the 1-D structure ensures the Series are placed in a single cell.

Append your Series to a dict construct the Series of Series with the basic constructor and make it a DataFrame with `Series.to_frame`

```
d = {}
for i in range(2):
    d[i] = pd.Series([2, 4, 5]*(i+1))

df = pd.Series(d).to_frame('Data')

# Check they're Series
print(df.applymap(type))
#                                  Data
#0  <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
#1  <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```